# .htaccess issue with my domain name

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a domain name: `designfrags.com` where I've installed WordPress.

So, I'm using  `www.designfrags.com` to do blogging.

But, inside this domain, I have a directory named 'as' (which means 'as' is a sub-directory). I'm able to access this site using the URL: `http://designfrags.com/as` but not able to access using the 2 following URLs:

```
http://www.designfrags.com/as
http://as.designfrags.com
```

Can someone please help me ? The issue could be related to WordPress or .htaccess file - but I don't know what it is.

Here are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This was generated by WordPress but I since I have very little idea of how .htaccess works, I am helpless.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It would help us to know the actual domain name

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it fixes the problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick alongside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you won't be able to access it at abcabc.xyzxyz.com, as it's a subfolder not a subdomain.

You should be able to access it via www.xyzxyz.com/abcabc - some reasons why you wouldn't:

- the alias www isn't mapped in your domains' DNS
- a problem with your .htaccess - edit your original question, adding in the contents of your .htaccess file, and we'll try to help

**Update**

So, knowing your domain name, I can see that there is no www in your dns. You need to add (or ask your host to add `www` as a CNAME resolving to your hostname. Something like this:

```
www 14400 IN CNAME designfrags.com
```

Comment: +1 The `as.yourdomain.com` has no corresponding DNS record. @Aditya You will have to create `A` or `CNAME` DNS record first for `as` subdomain and point it to the same IP as your domain.

Comment: @adam a little late, but i am unable to see any ticks next to your answer.